# I can't seem to get the shortcut key (#) for deleting to work in Gmail on OSx

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, osx

I am using Chrome on OS X with a UK keyboard and for some reason I cannot delete an email using <kbd>#</kbd>.

Pretty much every other email shortcut I use works but not this.

To get the hash key I am pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, could this be the issue? If so, is there a better way to access the <kbd>#</kbd> key?

Answer (score 1):

I'm from México using a Spanish-ISO keyboard on a MacBook.

The shortcut doesn't work with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> so I used the LAB tab on Gmail settings to add "Keyboard Shortcuts by Alan S" and it's working great!

Comment: Nowadays, to enable Custom Keyboard shortcuts go to Gmail Settings > Advanced

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to turn on the keyboard shortcuts under setting.

Answer (score 1):

I use key  <kbd>[</kbd> to delete gmail post I am currently reading ... by default keyboard shortcuts are disabled ... to activate this goto Gmail click on Settings cog -> Keyboard shortcuts -> On -> hit Save Changes at bottom ... [for details see](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that archives it not delete. `] / [ : Remove conversation from current view and go newer/older` - this  removes the "inbox" tag which effectively archives it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help <kbd>#</kbd> for me is on the same key as <kbd>~</kbd>, just to the right of the <kbd>'</kbd>/<kbd>@</kbd> key.

I think Mac keyboards differ from other keyboards even on UK layouts. ChromeOS is based on Linux, right? Maybe following some [advice](http://grammerjack.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/using-mac-keyboard-with-ubuntu-linux.html) for Ubuntu Linux might help?

Comment: Chrome is not ChromeOS.

Comment: lol oops. Should have read the question - I saw Chrome on OSx and read Chrome OS :)